# Edit displayed text

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am learning about linux and writing bash scripts.

Is it possible to display text with the `echo` command, and then go back and edit a portion of the text to be displayed in its place?

If `echo` does not do this, then in bash how do you prompt a user with a default string that they can edit or erase and replace?

Comment: You can use control characters.

Comment: you'll get a more specific answer if you include an example usecase in your question. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line to keep formatting from getting folded into one paragraph. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bash, to show the user a line of text and allow them to edit it, you can use `read` with default text and an env var, like this:

```
paul@home:~$ read -e -i "default command" FOO
--> default command (edit to "default cmd" <enter>)
paul@home:~$ echo $FOO
--> default cmd
```

Use `help read` in bash to learn more about read.

For something a little fancier, with various widgets, look at `dialog`.  Dialog has the disadvantage that it is not built into bash and so might not be installed.

To edit more than a line, run a text editor.  Some scripts let the end user choose the text editor by running `$EDITOR` instead of coding the script to run a specific editor like vi/emacs/nano.  Before using `$EDITOR`, make sure it isn't blank.